# Mysql order by issue with diffrent date

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

[image: consider]

> Consider the table i want an order in which the latest edit date
>   billno come at top and so on. Like in this case billno 11 has the
>   latest edit_date so all billno 11 entries come at top. And if the other
>   billno  have the latest edit_date then all entries of that billno come
>   at top.

Comment: Is there any query you tried, errors to check or something else?

Comment: Join to this query `(select max(edit_date) mEditDate,  billNo from table group by billNo)` on billNo then order by mEditDate  basically gernate the max bill date for each bill no in a subquery then use it for your order.

Comment: Can you share te full query. @xQbert

Comment: Nope.  I don't know the query to get your data that you posted in a  pic. without it I don't know several things needed to generate such a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id, billNo, amount, edit_date
from [whatever tables and join conditions you need here]
order by edit_date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is th final query which i want and i finally got it.
[image]